# Magento 2.1.7 how to get different domain name for different stores

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7, stores

How can i get different domains name for different stores created.
Created store name as French its domain name should be fr.domainname.com.Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you want multiple websites in Magento 2 ?

Comment: Yeah i have multiple country so i need multiple websites as in format fr.domainname.com for french store  Aditya Shah

Comment: Okay sharing a solution.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: let me know if you have any query

Comment: Hi Aditya Shah i have given base url french.localhost/magento but it redirecting to admin panel

Comment: Please share screen shot

Comment: you're passing wrong base url

Comment: Please check my screenshot and tell me where i went wrong..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83936/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-trilok-kumar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1: Create websites**

---

1. In your Magento backend, go to

> Stores > Settings > All Stores

[image]

2. On the Stores page, click Create Website.

[image]

- Name: Enter a name to identify the website.
- Code: Enter a unique code; for example, if you have a French store,
  you can enter
- `french`
- Sort Order: Enter an optional numerical sort order.

---

3. Click Save Web Site.
4. Repeat these tasks as many times as necessary to create your websites.

---

**Step 2: Create stores**

- In your Magento backend, go to Stores > Settings > All Stores.
- On the Stores page, click Create Store.
  [image]

**Web Site**: Select the website with which to associate this store.
**Name**: Enter a name to identify the store.
**Root Category**: Select the root category for this store.On the Stores page, click Create Store.

- Click Save Store.
- Repeat these tasks as many times as necessary to create your stores.

**Step 3: Create store views**

---

- In your Magento backend, go to Stores > Settings > All Stores.
- On the Stores page, click Create Store View.
  [image]

**Store**: Select the store with which to associate this store view.

**Name**: Enter a name to identify this store view.

**Code**: Enter a unique name to identify this store view.

**Status**: Select Enabled.

**Sort Order**: Enter an optional numerical sort order.

- Click Save Store View.
- Repeat these tasks as many times as necessary to create your store
  views.

  ---

**Step 4: Change the website’s base URL**

- In your Magento backend, go to Stores > Settings > Configuration.
  Under General section, click Web.
- From the Store View list at the top of the page, select a website.
- Expand Base URLs section.

[image]

- Enter this website’s URL. For example: https://subdomain.example.com/
- Click Save Config.
- Repeat these tasks for other websites.

---

**Step 5: Add the store code to the base URL**

> Magento gives you the option to add the store code to the site’s base
>   URL, which simplifies the process of setting up multiple stores. Using
>   this option, you don’t have to create directories on the Magento file
>   system to store index.php and .htaccess.

This prevents index.php and .htaccess from getting out of sync with the Magento codebase in future upgrades.

- In your Magento backend, go to Stores > Settings > Configuration.
  Under General section, click Web.
- From the Store View list at the top of the page, select Default
  Config.
- Expand Url Options section.

[image]

- Uncheck the Use system value box next to Add Store Code to Urls. Then
  set this to Yes.
- Click Save Config.
- If prompted, flush the Magento cache. (System > Cache Management).

---

**Step 6: Change the default store view’s base URL**

> You must perform this step last because after it’s done, you’ll lose
>   access to the Magento Admin; your access returns after you set up
>   virtual hosts as discussed in the web-server-specific topics.

- In your Magento backend, go to Stores > Settings > Configuration.
  Under General section, click Web.
- From the Store View list at the top of the page, select Default
  Config. Expand Base URLs section.
- Enter your website’s base URL. For example: https://www.example.com/
  Click Save Config.

**Step 7: It’s done! You have successfully set up multiple websites and stores in Magento 2**

Comment: Hi Aditya Shah i  have given base url http://french.localhost/magento/ but it redirecting to admin panel

Comment: please remove the cache

Comment: @RohanHapani is there any way to use 2 different domains by using 1 magento backend ex - www.abc.com. www.xyz.com using 1 magento 2 backend)